# Bootstrap: Vertically Fluid Container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

My web-application is required to resize (i.e. shrink to fit) on very small and large screens.

While `<div class="container-fluid">` allows this feature horizontally, I have been unable to find any method of ensuring this vertically.

To clarify, how do I go about resizing the page to use exactly 100% of the viewport height so that even if the amount of content exceeds that it will shrink to fit?

Comment: Clarify your question... it sounds like you want the page to use exactly 100% of the viewport height, regardless if the amount of content would exceed that or not.  And somehow, if it did exceed, shrink everything programmatically to fit?